# JSP, useBean action

Tags: jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

By means of the useBean action I create a bean instance in one JSP page and woudl like to access this instance in another JSP page but the instance seems not to exist there, however I set the scope of the bean to "session". Could you advise why?

The code in the **JSP** where the **bean is created**:

> ```
> <jsp:useBean id="littleBean" class="beans.MyBean" scope="session">
>   <jsp:setProperty name="littleBean" property="name" value="The value set in the independent JSP page"/>
> </jsp:useBean>
> ```

The code to **access** the bean:

> ```
> <jsp:useBean id="littleBean" class="beans.MyBean" scope="session">
>     <jsp:getProperty name="littleBean" property="name" />
> </jsp:useBean>
> ```

The filed `String name` exists in the bean with the appropriate public setter and getter methods. Thanks in advance. Tamas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I have just seen it after sending the post. The problem is that I wrapped the getProperty in the useBean action and in this case it creates a new bean instance. The correct code that works for the access is without the `<jsp:useBean ...>` action:

> ```
> <jsp:getProperty name="littleBean" property="name" />
> ```

I have already tested it. Maybe it will also be useful to someone else.